# Dash Aggrid force scroll to bottom in Python

Tags: python, ag-grid, plotly-dash

I'm trying to build a simple `Dash` app that loads an Excel and populates the data into an `Aggrid`.

Then, I want to be able to add/delete rows.

I start by using the code as shown in the example here:

https://github.com/Coding-with-Adam/Dash-by-Plotly/blob/master/Ag-Grid/row-deletion/add-delete-rows.py

However, every time I add a row, the scroll jumps to the top.

I tried to add the following:

```
table = dag.AgGrid(
    id="portfolio-table",
    className="ag-theme-alpine-dark",
    columnDefs=columnDefs,
    rowData=df.to_dict("records"),
    columnSize="sizeToFit",
    scrollTo={'rowPosition':'bottom'},
    defaultColDef=defaultColDef,
    dashGridOptions={"rowSelection":"multiple", "undoRedoCellEditing": True},
)
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.

Did someone manage to solve this?

Thank you